JS Programatically set the value of a file input field
I'm trying to post a large binary object via a <form> element. There is an old version that posts it using a b64 encoded string in a <input type="hidden"> field, but the payload data gets much larger than the web server allows.
As a solution, I'm trying to put the raw data in binary via a <input type="file"> field instead, so I can avoid the b64 inflation. Is this even possible?
The current code looks like this:
function submitToServer(evt) {
  evt?.preventDefault?.()

  const myForm = document.querySelector('form#RequestModal'),
    data = new FormData(myForm)

  let fetchData = [
    fetch(_API_ENDPOINT_ . '/path/to/controller', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    }),
    // Other fetches...
  ]

  Promise.all(fetchData)
    .then([uploadRes, tokenRes, serversStatus])
      // ...
    })
    .catch(E => {
      // ...
    })
}

As you might have guessed, the <form> element has a number of hidden input fields that are filled programmatically. I'm trying to replace these fields with file input fields (hidden by css).
Update: This is not a duplicate of /questions/47119426. The main reason is that I've been trying to put the blob data into a <input type="file"> so that when the <form> element is parsed by the native JS constructor FormData, it collects the blob content instead of having to add it through an append call.
The solution wasn't what I was looking for directly, but create an auxiliary function that takes the <form> element as argument, and such element has a store identifier, then such auxiliary function retrieves the blobs from the associated store and appends it's content to the FormData, and finally returns it. It's a bit more complex, but simple enough to understand for project newcomers.
One last note: I might publish a function that doesn't violate my NDA contract because it's a very simple solution that can be easily customized and I find this solution very useful, but you know how intellectual property contracts work...

I don't think you can do this as `input type="file" just stores the path to the file, not the contents of the file. Have you considered just posting the data via an AJAX request?

Where does the blob (large binary object) come from in your code?

What are you doing with data? Where do method, body, headers come from?

No, you cannot set the value of an <input type="file"> (as in, have the browser read some arbitrary file from the user's computer).
But you don't need to! You're working with a FormData object already, to which you can simply append your Blob under any name before sending the data.

"as in, have the browser read some arbitrary file from the user's computer" that's not what they're asking for though, they want to set an already accessible Blob, which is possible.

@Kaiido Oh, interesting, thanks! Still they shouldn't need to do that.
